# Finding $\cos\theta$ from diagram

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> I recently took a test and was confused about a question. I feel that
>   the answer is B. Could anyone please elucidate it. Thanks!

The point $(−4, 3)$ is on the terminal side of angle $\theta$ as sketched below. Find $\cos\theta$.

[image: terminal_side_of_angle]

A.  $-(4/5)$

B.  $-(3/4)$

C. $-(\sqrt{2}/2)$

D.   $(\sqrt{3}/2)$

E.   $(4/5)$

Comment: Your feeling is wrong. Compute the length of the hypotenuse. Divide the adjacent side by the hypotenuse. Note from the diagram that $\cos \theta < 0$.

Comment: Do you know the geometric interpretations of your trig functions?  Have you learned the mnemonic "SOH-CAH-TOA"?

Comment: @DougM Yes, I have learnt the mnemonic. Also thanks everyone for answering. I understood the explanation. Looking forward to learning with Mathematics SE!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty easy to show (and might even be given in most textbooks) that
$$\cos(\pi - \alpha) = -\cos(\alpha)$$ for any angle $\alpha$.

Note that the angle opposite $\theta$ in your diagram is found by computing $\pi-\theta$. Since it is pretty easy to get that $\cos(\pi-\theta) = \frac{-4}{5}$ from the diagram, we have the following:

$$-\cos(\theta) = \cos(\pi-\theta) = -\frac{4}{5}$$
thus $\cos(\theta) = -(-\frac{4}{5}) = \frac{4}{5}.$

Comment: The way I read this $\theta$ is the second-quadrant angle shown in the diagram.  Therefore, $\cos\theta = -\frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct now that I look at the diagram better. Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is A. The hypotenuse in the following figure has length $5$ by Pythagoras:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The number you computed is $\tan\theta = -\frac{3}{4}$.  If an angle is in standard position (vertex at the origin, initial side on the positive $x$-axis) and $(x, y)$ is the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the circle with radius $r$ with center at the origin, then 
\begin{align*} 
\sin\theta & = \frac{y}{r} & \csc\theta & = \frac{r}{y}\\[2mm] 
\cos\theta & = \frac{x}{r} & \sec\theta & = \frac{r}{x}\\[2mm] 
\tan\theta & = \frac{y}{x} & \cot\theta & = \frac{x}{y}
\end{align*}

With that in mind, consider the figure below.

[image: terminal_side_of_second-quadrant_angle_intersects_circle_with_radius_5]

By the Pythagorean Theorem, the point $(-4, 3)$ lies on a circle with radius $5$ and center at the origin.  Hence, we have $x = -4$, $y = 3$, and $r = 5$.  Therefore, 
$$\cos\theta = \frac{x}{r} = -\frac{4}{5}$$